# Get Android shared preferences value in activity/normal class

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have made a shared preference activity that store the user settings, now i want to get values in a activity or normal java class.please provide a solution or example i have already tried this code but failed.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SharedPreferences channel=this.getSharedPreferences(strFile, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    strChannel=channel.getString(keyChannel,"Default").toString();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), strChannel, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

in this code `strfile` for eg. `com.android.pack.ClassName` is `SharedPreference Activity` from values to be fetched, and keyChannel is key that is same in `SharedPreference Activity`.

Kindly provide the solution.

Comment: What does this code produce? Any exceptions thrown?

Comment: do you get any errors? this does not work is that what you are saying?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

If you have a SharedPreferenceActivity by which you have saved your values

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String imgSett = prefs.getString(keyChannel, "");
```

if the value is saved in a SharedPreference in an Activity then this is the correct way to saving it.

```
SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
editor.putString(keyChannel, email);
editor.commit();// commit is important here.
```

and this is how you can retrieve the values.

```
SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
String channel = (shared.getString(keyChannel, ""));
```

Also be aware that you can do so in a non-Activity class too but the only condition is that you need to pass the context of the Activity. use this context in to get the SharedPreferences.

```
mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: I am not able to understand one thing that is the difference between 

SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String channel = (shared.getString(keyChannel, "")); 

and this

SharedPreferences channel=this.getSharedPreferences(strFile, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);    
strChannel=channel.getString(keyChannel,"Default").toString();     

kindly tell one thing what will be the value of PREF_NAME, please provide the example, may be i am giving wrong path of class. I gave 
    
    String strFile="com.android.pref.PrefClass";

Comment: There PRE_NAME is only a String. It could be anything eg: your application name, your name, your class name etc. There is absolutely no diff betwwen the two statements. what is your output BTW

Comment: it shows blank toast, but i confused, how can new activity know which preference to be fetched. please explain what will the matching paramter by which a perticular value can be get...

Comment: if i putt some value in getString(key,"Default") then is give Default on Toast.

Comment: the PREF_NAME should be the same in all your Activities accross your application. It is the key that changes. SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); this line reserves a pool of memory space inside the app memory. when you use the following line ... editor.putString(keyChannel, val);
a space is created and val is stored in it, and can be identified by the variable keyChannel.

Comment: can u please give me samlpe of this code, means there should be a shared pref activity and one normal activity or class,

Comment: read this.. this post has an in depth discussion on SharedPreference and PreferenceActivity...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614719/how-do-i-get-the-sharedpreferences-from-a-preferenceactivity-in-android

Comment: Finaly i found the solution and now its working fine. i just add  SharedPreferences shared = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);  String val=shared.getString("key", "defValue"); Thanks

Comment: What has been missing is the default name, since it isn't specified anywhere. "com.package.name_preferences.xml"  This little bread crumb solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 5):

I tried this code, to retrieve shared preferences from an activity, and could not get it to work:

```
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    sharedPreferences.getAll();
    Log.d("AddNewRecord", "getAll: " + sharedPreferences.getAll());
    Log.d("AddNewRecord", "Size: " + sharedPreferences.getAll().size());
```

Every time I tried, my preferences returned 0, even though I have 14 preferences saved by the preference activity.
I finally found the answer. I added this to the preferences in the onCreate section.

getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName("defaultPreferences");

After I added this statement, my saved preferences returned as expected. I hope that this helps someone else who may experience the same issue that I did.

Answer (score 1):

This is the procedure that seems simplest to me:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("MySharedPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor e = sp.edit();

    if (sp.getString("sharedString", null).equals("true")
            || sp.getString("sharedString", null) == null) {
        e.putString("sharedString", "false").commit();
        // Do something
    } else {
        // Do something else
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You use uninstall the app and change the sharedPreferences name then run this application. I think it will resolve the issue.

A sample code to retrieve values from sharedPreferences you can use the following set of code,

```
SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
String channel = (shared.getString(keyValue, ""));
```