# save value with on click in shared prefrences

Tags: android

i have 9 item list and i want when user click on each item save value in shared SharedPreferences and in second activity put if value save in SharedPreferences equal for example a
how can i do this work 
please help me

```
 @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {      



mSharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("edameh", 0);

    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = mSharedPreferences.edit();



    if (i == 0) {
        Intent intent0 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Study.class);
        startActivity(intent0);
 edit.putString("a", ed);
        edit.commit();


    }
    if (i == 1) {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Mogh.class);
        startActivity(intent1);

 edit.putString("b", ed);
        edit.commit();
    }
```

in second activity for check value shared prefrences

```
 if (fistActivity.ed=="a"){


    }
```

Comment: You really should Google this yourself and try something. How about [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

Comment: can you help me im tryed  some code but not working

Comment: Can you show us what you tried that isn't working? It's unclear of what you actually want to save in shared preferences.

Comment: what i am doing please help me

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496840/get-android-shared-preferences-value-in-activity-normal-class

Comment: can you more explain for my code