# get SharedPreferences value in a non activity file in android?

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I have a class  with all common functions and there i want to get some of sharedpreferences value. below code getSharedPreference() is giving error.

Here's my code:

```
public class CommonFunctions {

Context mContext;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    public CommonFunctions(Context context) {
       this.mContext = context;
       sharedPreferences = getSharedPreference("MyPREFERENCES", MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

}
```

Is there any way to get value in java class?

Comment: you have to use context.getSharedPreference("MyPREFERENCES", context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: You can't directly use context related functions outside of activity

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7497079/3983054

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Android shared preferences value in activity/normal class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496840/get-android-shared-preferences-value-in-activity-normal-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code;

```
 sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreference("MyPREFERENCES", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: here MODE_PRIVATE is not resolved error is generating.

Comment: write this  Context.MODE_PRIVATE

Comment: plz tick my answer if this will helpful for you