# Sharedpreferences in android

Tags: java, android

Well, I am beginner in Android and java, but I'm trying to learn.

My question is. I have these methods in my class (to save and load Sharedpreferences):

```
private String Load_pref(String key){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String strSavedMem1 = sharedPreferences.getString(key, "");        
    return strSavedMem1;
   } 

public void Save_pref(String key, String value){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
   }
```

Well, Its work well, but I would call these methods from another class (other screen activity). I tried to do this in my other activity:

```
            MyActivity1 A = new MyActivity1();
            A.Save_pref("ACCOUNT","Myname");
```

The code compiles without problem, but the program crashes in this part of the code.
Someone could help me solve this problem?

Thanks,
Alexandre

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an instance of the activity *just* to access a set of shared preferences is extremely heavyweight.  Notice they're called *Shared* Preferences :)  Really what you want to do is call PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences().  Rather than repeat the whole solution, I'll just link you to where this has already been explained on StackOverflow, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614719/how-do-i-get-the-sharedpreferences-from-a-preferenceactivity-in-android).  Enjoy!

Comment: Very Thanks, this answer was very helpful to me, problem solved