# android access default shared preferences from different packages

Tags: android, package, preferences

I have an Android application with more source packages. In the base package I have a PreferenceActivity used to configure the preferences of the app. From all the activities within the same package as the PreferenceActivity, I can access these preferences by using `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());`

However, from another package, activities use another shared preferences file when I call `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());`. This stops me from accessing the preferences from the PreferenceActivity.

How can I solve this? I want to retrieve the same shared preferences in every package in the application.

Comment: you mean java source package or diefferent application?

Comment: source package from same application

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use a name for the shared preference and then get the same name for all the applications? Look under shared preferences at: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Edit: I think what you look after is here, no reason to take out parts as it gives a pretty good explanation: [How do I get the SharedPreferences from a PreferenceActivity in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614719/how-do-i-get-the-sharedpreferences-from-a-preferenceactivity-in-android)

Comment: Normally I would. But since I'm using a PreferenceActivity, I cannot do this, as it seems that one cannot give a name to the SharedPreferences used by a PrefenceActivity

Comment: Well you could always call a new activity from your shared activity and then make that activity save the content :S but seems like an awfull hack. I can't see why a preferenceactivity should be any different from a regular activity, the real problem might be that you can't use shared preferences in this way....

Comment: If you can't make this work I suggest using another way for data storage.

Comment: True. Another approach that I thought of would be to simply register a listener for each Preference in the PreferenceActivity. When the preference value is changed, I'd also change that preference into my SharedPreferences.

Comment: Something like this: `checkBoxPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new MyListener());`. In the body of onPreferenceClick() in MyListener, I write something like this: `getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, Preferences.WORLD_WRITABLE).edit().putBoolean(checkBoxPreference.getKey(), checkBoxPreference.isChecked()).commit();` Still, this is an undesirable hack, since I have the same values stored twice, i.e. they get saved in 2 preference files

Comment: Updated answer with link to a perfect answer :)