# What is use of preference activity in android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have studied preference activity but I don't understand it. Can anybody tell me what is the use of preference activity? How does it differ from activity?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

PreferencesActivity is a way to easily create preference screens such as those in Android itself, just look under `Settings`. These can be used inside applications to easily save preferences to [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and then [easily access these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614719/how-do-i-get-the-sharedpreferences-from-a-preferenceactivity-in-android) from within your app.

See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) page for more information on PreferenceActivity.

An example of a PreferenceActivity showing some preferences:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

### Use:

It gives a very easy way to create a standard looking settings screen for any application.

### Why:

minimal coding is required

### How it works:

it takes care of UI.The values are stored in SharedPreferences automatically by the PreferenceActivity and so its scope becomes app wide.

### Sample Screen UI:

[image: Preference Activity]

Answer (score 1):

such settings screen, you can use it for your app where user want to change setting.

Answer (score 0):

Its one stop to manage your Shared Preferences. Through this, you can provide a group of **Settings** to user for your app. Since it only deals with preferences, that's why its different from regular Activity. Read [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-application-preferences/) for more info

Answer (score 0):

PreferenceActivity supports the simple handling of preferences. It can show a set of preferences to the user.

An activity on the other hand is a single thing a user can do.

Checkout Section 13 at this [link](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html#preferences)

Answer (score 0):

It is usually  used to create a  settings screen for  applications .The values are stored in SharedPreferences automatically as soon as user selects a preference setting. It frees the programmer from explicitly saving preference values.

Answer (score 0):

PreferenceActivity is a class that allows you to implement an activity that realizes a hierarchical organization of choices. Most often it provides a good bases for building the settings activity in you application.