# Storing data in SharedPreferences accessible to all activities

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to store and retrieve data that is accessible to all activities in my app using SharedPreferences. Is that possible? Up until now I have been doing it such that the data is stored for a particular activity.

Comment: You can also use the default preference file, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614719/how-do-i-get-the-sharedpreferences-from-a-preferenceactivity-in-android)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. SharePreferences do exactly this.
In every activity you can this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ApplicationConstants.PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString(name, value);
editor.commit();
```

And then retrieve values in other activty doing this:

```
mPrefs.getString(name, "");
```

This is the documentation: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

And this is a good example to start with:

http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.it/2012/03/android-preferenceactivity.html

Comment: really helpfull thnx :)

Comment: This seems useful, but is it up to date? I wonder what "ApplicationConstants" is, and I cannot find any information about it in the documentation. Also, the good example in that blog is gone. It makes sense though, I realize answer was given 5 years ago.

Comment: ApplicationConstants would be a constant defined in the constants file in app or there is a java class named ApplicationConstants ,  you can simply pass  a string there but make sure the string is same everywhere you use it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's the whole purpose of it.

Here's how you should write to it, via `Editor`

```
    final SharedPreferences shp         = ctx.getSharedPreferences(ctx.getString(R.string.app_name), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor ed   = shp.edit(); 
    ed.putString("var1", "var1");
    ed.putString("var2", "var2");
```

And to load it:

```
shp.getString("var1", "defvalue");
```

Comment: OK, it's called getSharedPreferences. I was only using getPreferences. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have a better version. As sometimes when you try to do **getSharedPreferences** you might get an error as it could not be found. 
This is how I store values in my Android projects.

**Add**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=this.getSharedPreferences("packagename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

 sharedPreferences.edit().putString("username", "specify name here").apply();
```

**Package Name** can be directly copied from top of the activity ex: com.example.name.projectname

**Retrieve**

```
String username = sharedPreferences.getString("username","");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access values in all of your activities I think the better way is storing in a custom Application class and later in activities you can:

```
((CustomApplication)getApplication()).getStoredValue()
```

Shared preferences are stored in files and this file access is slower.

Answer (score 0):

Is my example for create function for set and get an object data called "USER"

**For set sharePreference data**

```
public void saveUser(User usuario) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("A", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); // sharedpreference set named "A"

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString("name", usuario.getNombre());
        editor.putString("username", usuario.getUsername());
        editor.putString("pass", usuario.getContrasena());
        editor.putString("roll",usuario.getRol());
        editor.commit();
    }
```

**For get sharePreference data**

```
public Usuario getUser() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("A", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);   // sharedpreference set named "A"
        User usuario = new User();
        usuario.setNombre(sharedPref.getString("name", "null"));
        usuario.setUsername(sharedPref.getString("username", "null"));
        usuario.setContrasena(sharedPref.getString("pass", "null"));
        usuario.setRol(sharedPref.getString("roll", "null"));
        return usuario;
    }
```

**Important:** set name to sharePreference in this case "A"