# Android: change variables (counters) of a closed application using a service

Tags: android, service, sharedpreferences, android-contentprovider

stackoverflow community.

I have a problem that I've been trying to solve since a few days ago.

**I have a service running in an Android application that receives and sends messages. For those messages, I have counters that save the ammount of sent and received sms and errors.** For example, when a message is sent, the counter adds +1 and shows the total on screen (in a not focusable editview).

Another thing I do is bind my service, so I can switch it on or off according to my needs. **Everything works fine when the application is running, but if it is finished my variables are lost, but I need to keep counting the messages somehow and show the values when the user opens the application again. How can I do this?**

I've been using shared preferences variables to save these numbers and others configurations, but when the app is killed, those numbers can't keep increasing.

When the application is closed, can I save the counters values somewhere? Can I access to the shared preferences from the service with the application closed? What if I use a content provider? Can I access to it from the running service even if the app is closed?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem accessing shared preferences from a service. So, just save your variables on your services onDestroy() method and reload them onCreate();

This should work to get the preferences:

```
Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
```

Here's a great answer: [How do I get the SharedPreferences from a PreferenceActivity in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614719/how-do-i-get-the-sharedpreferences-from-a-preferenceactivity-in-android)

Comment: Thanks for answering, hatcyl. Now the thing is if I kill the process where my application is running, every variable, including shared preferences, die. So, where can I increase the counter I need to later refresh it on the user's screen?

Comment: I solved it reading the link you shared and also the documentation. Thank you.