# How to use getSharedPreferences(String, int) in dialogpreference class?

Tags: android

When I tried to use getSharedPreferences(), eclipse gave me the android.Preference.preference.getSharePreferences() one, but not the one from contextWrapper which has 2 arguements. I tried to included the whole name which is android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(null, 0), but still doesn't work, eclipse said cannot make a static reference to a non static one.
Any idea? I don't have any problem calling the one with 2 arguments in other class such as activity though.

```
public class DialogExPreference extends DialogPreference implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener
{
    SharedPreferences settings;
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
    {
        if(which==-1)
        {
            if(!pw1.getText().toString().equals("")&&!pw2.getText().toString().equals(""))
            {

                if(pw1.getText().toString().equals(pw2.getText().toString()))
                {
                     settings =getSharedPreferences();// android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(null, 0);
                     Editor editor = settings.edit();
                     editor.putString("password", pw1.getText().toString());
                     editor.commit();                    


                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Password Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
.....
```

Comment: I think you need to specify something like getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

Comment: This method doesnt know what MODE_WORLD_READABLE nor 0 is

Comment: **ADVICE** you're calling getText() too much, only call it once.

Answer (score 0):

you can check below code might help one thing you can use application context

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreference("name_of_pref",MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putInt("storedInt", storedPreference); // value to store
editor.commit();
```

Also check link [Shared Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614719/how-do-i-get-the-sharedpreferences-from-a-preferenceactivity-in-android)