# Is it possible to save a variable value in Android (in memory), even after closing the application? If so, how?

Tags: android, variables, memory, storage

How is it possible to save a variable value in an Android app? Can the value be saved in memory? I am planning to save a float value in my application, so the next time the app is opened, the previous value will be loaded. How do I go about this? Shared Preferences or something else?

Comment: Does it have to be in memory, or can you save to disk?

Comment: As much as possible, it should be in memory.

Comment: Did you get answer you expected ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. `SharedPreferences` is the best available option.

To store float value:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putFloat("storedFloat", storedFloatPreference); // value to store
editor.commit();
```

Also check this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putFloat(java.lang.String,%20float)

Check this SO question. It nicely answers your question: [How do I get the SharedPreferences from a PreferenceActivity in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614719/how-do-i-get-the-sharedpreferences-from-a-preferenceactivity-in-android)

Comment: If I use SharedPreferences, how do I save float values using it?

Comment: @ChristopherTreanor http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values. if you search on stackoverflow you will find more posts related

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible use shared preferences.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

You can also use sqlite data base to store the data and retrieve when you need it.

Your other storage options. you could store your values to a file in memory.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Storage Options Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) to be sure you pick the most appropriate type for you but if its just one value then `SharedPreferences` should work fine for you.

See [The Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) for a good example on how to use `SharedPreferences`