# PreferenceActivity addPreferencesFromResource deprecated

Tags: android

My app so far has been using the appcompat_v7 support library so that I can use fragments for my min target of api 8 and beyond. I just found out that PreferenceFragment requires API 11 and is not apart of the support library.

My question is it safe to use the deprecated addPreferenceFromResource even on API 11 and higher? So that I can maintain my target 8?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the SharedPreferences from a PreferenceActivity in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614719/how-do-i-get-the-sharedpreferences-from-a-preferenceactivity-in-android)

Comment: No, I am saying is there any problems using a deprecated on current APIs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, the question is about using `PreferenceActivity.addPreferencesFromResource()`. It's perfectly fine to use it if you are targeting API level prior to 11, because on that API levels it is not deprecated.

The only problem that may arise someday is that Google announces that from certain Android version it won't support some older API levels, which (I believe) isn't going to happen in observable future.

Comment: thanks, I will need to keep an eye out for changes they make. hopefully they will add preferenceFragment to support library