# Parse remember user when offline on Android devices

Tags: android, parse-platform, offline

I can add data to parse when I'm offline, but my app will check if the user is logged in  when I turn it on. If I'm offline the app won't turn on. How to remember the last user on the device when I'm offline?

Comment: Store it in shared preferences?

Answer (score 0):

In your main activity make a change in `onStop()` or `onDestroy()`, getting the SharedPreferences and saving data in it. In `onCreate()` method try to obtain your values from SharedPreferences.
Follow this link for more information about SharedPreferences and how to use it
[How do I get the SharedPreferences from a PreferenceActivity in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614719/how-do-i-get-the-sharedpreferences-from-a-preferenceactivity-in-android)