# How can I send data across activities to display a message?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity

I'm creating something kinda simple I guess and I ran into a few issues.

The app scheme basically goes like that:
Main screen display's info/news -> drawer (user selects option) ->
-> open's a list -> upon clicking, 2 FAB's appear one for reading comments and one for sending one -> send FAB open's a form.

Now what I'm trying to do is have a "send" button (already done reading the reading of the info entered) and I want it to send it to the "reading" page where it'll stack one on another.

say reading page contains the message:
XXX YYY
and another user sends ZZZ UUU
the reading page will become:
ZZZ UUU 
XXX YYY

I will make the reading page with a send button instead of 2 activities in the near future but it's also for expanding my knowledge.

How can I send the data and have the message displayed on the reading screen?

Also, how can I create a dynamic page for the reading for every section of the list? instead of creating over 100 reading pages?

Thanks :)

Comment: You should post what you have done so far, and post the second question in another entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use putExtra on your intent

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("My_Extra_Param", extra);
    startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

For sending data between **Activities** you must send data with `intent` to other **Activity**.

Look at this : [How do I pass data between activities on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android)

OR

Also you can save your temporary data into `Sharedpreferences` and retrive into another **Activity**

see this tutorials : [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values) , [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614719/how-do-i-get-the-sharedpreferences-from-a-preferenceactivity-in-android)