# Get app's SharedPreferences in Android?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to make a library/module for my project which will show all of the SharedPreferences of an application.

One way to get all the SharedPreferences is:

```
Map<String,?> keys = prefs.getAll();  // app sharedPreference

for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : keys.entrySet()){
    Log.d("map values",entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue().toString()); 
}
```

Now I am trying to get all preferences of an application without knowing the application preferences.

```
Map<String,?> keys = prefs.getAll(); // app sharedPreference (without knowing prefs)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: that can be a security issue if apps are storing important information in shared preferences

Comment: Best way is just to try out. From the docs it looks like it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it should work, if anything is there... Just tested the following, and got nothing in return.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
Map<String,?> keys = prefs.getAll();  // app sharedPreference

Log.d("- Starting -", "Printing");
for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : keys.entrySet()){
    Log.d("map values",entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue().toString());
}
Log.d("--- End ---", "Printing");
```

What I use myself to store sharedPreffs is something like the following. And if some ones uses that, you are going to have a very hard time, if not impossible to get the data from it.

```
context.getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

For more information and good use of sharedPreferences please look [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614719/how-do-i-get-the-sharedpreferences-from-a-preferenceactivity-in-android)

Comment: i added some value into sharedPreference. Then i tried as you suggested, and got nothing in return.